# TypeError, send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I added a boolean, so that the property title is not changeable on the front-end, but I get this error.

```
TypeError at /contacts/contact
send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/contact
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            property_id = request.POST['property_id']
            if 'property' in request.POST:
                property = request.POST['property']
            else:
                property = False

            name = request.POST['name']
            email = request.POST['email']
            message = request.POST['message']
            realtor_email = request.POST['realtor_email']

            contact = Contact(property=property, property_id=property_id, name=name, message=message )

            contact.save()

            # Send Email
            send_mail(
                'Property Inquiry',
                'There has been an inquiry for' + property + 'Check it',
                ['m@gmail.com', 'j@gmail.com'],
                fail_silently=False
            )
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

update:
This code did the trick

```
'There has been an inquiry for' + str(property) + 'Check it',
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: there's a comma missing after `'Property Inquiry'`

Comment: when you want to concatenate str with boolean you should convert boolean to str too like `'There has been an inquiry for' + str(property) + 'Check it'`

Comment: when I try to convert boolean to str I get a 'send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'' Error

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing `,` in send_mail function, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first is from, the second in [] is the mailing list

```
        # Send Email
        send_mail(
            'Property Inquiry',
            'There has been an inquiry for' + property + 'Check it',
            'your_account@gmail.com',
            ['m@gmail.com','j@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False
        )
```